# BadParcelableException in android.gms.maps on release but not in debug mode

Tags: android, google-maps, proguard, badparcelableexception

My app crashes when accessing to an activity that uses google maps (v.2). I am getting `android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.maps.f`

This happens only in release mode, but there is no error or warning in logs when I am in debug mode.

I am using Proguard on Eclipse IDE to obfuscate the code, so I guess this could be the problem. I have googled around but I have not found a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using `proguard.cfg` from Google Maps Android API v2 samples.

It is located in `ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps`.

This part is what you want to include:

```
# The maps library uses custom Parcelables.  Use this rule (which is slightly
# broader than the standard recommended one) to avoid obfuscating them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}
```

but maybe other too.

Comment: Thanks @MaciejGórski. What you propose I had already included.
Now what I have done is to include 

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { 
    public *;
    protected *;
}

-keep interface com.google.android.gms.** { *; } 

and that works